# How check if data is already in cache OkHttp

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

I followed [this](https://medium.com/@I_Love_Coding/how-does-okhttp-cache-works-851d37dd29cd) tutorial to implement a cache using ETags, however how can a request with a query check the cache first? For example lets say you have an endpoint `GET /Todos` that gets a list of Todo notes, then you have a `GET /Todos/{id}` that gets a todo for a particular id. If I get all todos first, then try to fetch one for a particular id, is there any way to check if that item is already in the cache (since it would be previously cached when you fetched all items)?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE` on the request. If you get a response with status code 504, it wasn’t in the cache.

Comment: That wont work. `GET /Todos/{id}` would return a 503 in that case because that particular request had not been made yet and thus it was not cached, even though that same data via a different request (`GET /Todos`) had been cached

Comment: It should be 504 Unsatisfiable Request